# How to identify the loops to apply Kirchhoff's voltage law in these circuits?

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

Here is what I know so far regarding KVL. To apply KVL to a circuit, the nodes of the circuit must be identified. Then we identify loops in the circuit (a loop starts at a node, travels along one or more branches and ends at the start node). Then apply KVL to the loop.

My problem is with circuits such as a the following
[image]
[image]

I am having some difficulty in finding the loops in the circuits to apply KVL.

In schematic on the left, because Vcc and ground are drawn as single lines not connected to anything, I don't understand how to form loops to include V<sub>cc</sub> and the wire from the transistor's emitter to apply KVL.

Similarly, in the schematic on the right, I don't understand how to include the 10V source in a loop.

I am able to solve circuit analysis questions using Kirchhoff's laws when there are "closed" connections in a circuit. But components like the ones in the above schematics confuse me.

Can someone please help me understand these schematics?

Comment: Assume a battery or other power source connected between Vcc and Ground.

Comment: @PeterBennett, your comment needs to be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2felcIV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

First loop (Blue)

$$V_{CC} - I_BR_B+Vbe = 0$$

Second loop (Red)

$$V_{CC} - I_CR_C - V_{CE}$$

And for the second circuit with voltage divider:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKjm4Z.png)</sup>

[image]

Input loops
(Blue)
$$V_{CC} - (I_B+I_2)R_1 - I_2R_2=0$$ 
(Green)
$$ I_2R_2 = V_{BE}+I_ER_E$$

And the output loop

(Red)
$$V_{CC} - I_CR_C - V_{CE} -I_ER_E $$

Comment: Great answer. It will be more helpful to understand if you explicitly declare the transistor as a combination of the equivalent elements you are assuming it to be, i.e. a voltage source (Vbe) from emitter to base and a dependent source (Ic = beta*Ib) between the emitter and collector.