# KVL on circuit with transistor

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

I have a question regarding applying KVL in a circuit with a npn-transistor. Unfortunately this is badly documented in the textbook, and I couldn't find the answer so far.

For the circuit below, it was given that V_BE = 0.7, and from this V_CE = 0.8V is derived. This was derived from V_DD = V_CE + V_BE. This is where my confusion stems from, wouldn't using KVL give the equation V_DD = V_CE? I don't see how to use KVL correctly in this circuit.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have two transistors connected in series between the positive terminal of a supply voltage and the GND. The upper one **Q2** is "working" as a diode.

Thus, for **Q2** we have **Vce2 = Vbe2 = 0.7V**

Because the **Q2** base terminal is directly connected to the collector.

And from KVL we have this:

$$ V_{DD} = V_{BE2} + V_{CE1} $$

So we can easily find the **Vce1** value

$$V_{CE1} = V_{DD} - V_{BE2} = 1.5V - 0.7V = 0.8V$$

And we done.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f080qh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the help! A bit confused on why V_DD = V_BE2 + V_CE1 holds through KVL though, what loop is chosen for this? And also should V_DD be seen as some kind of battery between the "ground" and the upper line? Also why isn't I_E1 not 0 since it's grounded?
(sorry I really don't have the background for this)

Comment: The loop is  +VDD (battery)---> Vbe1---->Vce1---->GND---->-VDD. And VDD is a battery (voltage source) as I have shown on my circuit schematic.

Comment: Take a look at this example https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/312063/how-to-identify-the-loops-to-apply-kirchhoffs-voltage-law-in-these-circuits/312067#312067